# Is 55ns SRAM fast enough to drive low resolution VGA?

Tags: speed, vga, sram

I can't seem to wrap my head around the math.

Assuming I want a `640x480x256` VGA signal, and I had an FPGA or fast micro-controller to drive it, would `55ns` be able to handle it?

Meaning each byte of the 8-bit memory would translate to one pixel.  Also assuming my R-2R ladder was setup to something like `RRRGGBBB`.

I have a very specific reason to use DIP SRAM.  I can find speeds down to about `15ns` but small sizes.  The `512k` I want to buy tops out at `55ns`.

If someone could give me examples of how the bandwidth is calculated, it might help me decide to use the 512k or maybe do something different with multiple 15ns chips.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't weigh against green; results will be very grainy.

Comment: Pixel clock for 640x480 resolution is ~31MHz. Start from it.

Comment: That was just an example.  For my specific needs, I will probably use something like RRGGBBxx (xx = ignore) or maybe RRGGBBIx where I = intensity.

Comment: @EugeneSh that's what I'm having issues with.  I guess the translation from MHz to ns, etc. is confusing me.

Comment: huh? `1Hz = 1/1s` ...

Comment: Remember you can interleave more than one RAM chip for faster access.

Comment: 1 MHz is 1 microsecond. 1GHz is 1 nanosecond. 10 nanoseconds is 100 MHz. And so on.

Comment: 640x480x60Hz uses a 25 MHz pixel clock so you'd need 1 byte every 40 ns (for 73 % of the time). You also want to be able to write display data to your RAM so let's assume we want two RAM byte accesses in that 40 ns: one to read and display a pixel, one to R/W display data. So you can either buy faster RAM or wider RAM. A 32-bit wide RAM using 55 ns chips could serve up four bytes in one 60 ns read and they'd last 160 ns. This illustrates the arithmetic, you can explore the permutations further. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @TonyM that was very helpful!  That's the math I was looking for.  I can do the calculations...I just didn't know what numbers to plop in.

Comment: Glad to help and glad it helped :-) Posted it as an answer below, glad of the up-vote if you can do. Let us know what you design if I/we can help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

640x480x60Hz uses a 25 MHz pixel clock so you'd need 1 byte every 40 ns (for 73 % of the time).

You also want to be able to write display data to your RAM so let's assume we want two RAM byte accesses in that 40 ns: one to read and display a pixel, one to R/W display data.

So you can either buy faster RAM or wider RAM. A 32-bit wide RAM using 55 ns chips could serve up four bytes in one 60 ns read and they'd last 160 ns.

This illustrates the arithmetic, you can explore the permutations further. If you're using an FPGA, you can do some clever prefetching stuff to burst-read multiple dwords and get more R/W slots in between them.

Answer (score 4):

$$ {1 \over 55 \text{ ns} } = 18 \text{ MHz}.$$

640x480 @ 60 Hz VGA uses a pixel clock of 25.175 MHz, so there's no way you can drive that from a 55 ns SRAM. If you can't find a large enough 15 ns SRAM, you can group a couple of them together with an address decoder.

Comment: No address decoder, just a larger data bus.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it, but not (exactly) easily. As has been pointed out, 640x480x60 VGA requires a 25 MHz clock rate, or a 40 nsec access/cycle time. So, if you're in this all the way with your 55 nsec chips, is to use two of them. If you look at your pixels as being either odd or even (lsb of address being 0 or 1) it's clear that you can provide read addresses at 12.5 MHz while reading 2 bytes per clock, then driving the display at 25 MHz. Something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faMQHx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that, since there are now physically 2 ICs, they only need to be 256k.

Also, please keep in mind that writing to your RAM will cause display noise, since the display will pick up the write data as display data. Since you are doing pixel-level RAM control, rather than character, you will need to do a lot of writes, and therefore will have a lot of screen noise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the pixel rate. Using raw calculations for a 640x480 image including blank pixels, the VGA frame size could be 800x525. Since you are not going to use any intermediate buffers, your pixel rate @60fps must be 800x525x60 = 25.2MHz. That's a pixel rate.

Now, depending on the standard, like RGB or YUV4:2:2, and the bit depth (like 8bit), you will need 24bit and 16bit per pixel (3bytes and 2bytes respectively). Thus, your *byte*rate is tripple or double of the pixel rate.

In your case, you need to supply the each byte of data at 25.2MHz, whereas your 55ns memory can do it at ~18MHz, and 15ns can do it at 66MHz.

Answer (score -1):

640x480 a 1 byte per pixel at 30 frames is 9.2Mbytes/sec (640 x 480 x frame rate x bits per pixel), or to put it another way, with an 8bit data bus, 9.2Mtransfers a second. Now, you also need to be able to *write* that data *into* the ram equally fast, so that makes 18.4MT/s. 1/18.4MT = 54ns per transfer, right on the limit.

However, if you run at 25 or 20fps, you should be just fine as that would only need a cycle time of 65 and 81ns respectively which your 55ns SRAM should be able to handle comfortably.

You can always use two SRAMs together as a 16bit bus (you'd be reading two pixels at once instead of just one) this cuts your speed requirements in half but adds a bunch of extra pins.

Comment: This is incorrect, because real VGA signal has also some blanking times between lines. I mean the real pixel speed is higher. It's approximately 25 MHz, as duskwuff or TonyM already pointed out.

Comment: Unfortunately you've tried to average the data rate per second  and get a lower number. It's the peak transfer rate that's important. There'll be a lot of pixel reading then a pause between lines and at screen end. They could read a line slowly and buffer it in fast FPGA RAM and all sorts. But in truth, use the pixel clock period as the byte access period and then there's spare needed for display data R/W, as you say.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I kept thinking it was an LCD for some reason (where the update rate is a bit more arbitrary) I think it's time I went to bed before I give out any more bad advice