# Converting 100MHz clock to 65MHz clock for VGA

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl, vga, artix-series-fpga

I've written some HDL code to convert the frequency of the clock on FPGA (100MHz) to a freqency which is compatible with my VGA monitor (65MHz):

```
reg FLAG = 0;
reg [26:0]count;
always@(posedge clock)
begin
    if(reset)
    count <= 'd0;

    else if(count==65000000)
    begin
        FLAG = 1;
        count <= 'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
        count <= count+1;
        FLAG=0;
    end
end
```

The value of flag would keep changing from 0 to 1 with frquency of 65MHz, but that isin't apparenly working for me. Can someone point out the error here?
Also, is there a better way to convert one clock frequency to another?

Comment: 100000000 = 1 sec  ,  65000000 = 0.65 sec - you are not changing frequency

Comment: You cannot make 65MHz from 100MHz with counters. You would have to count a fraction of the time. If you count once with a 100MHz counter, the output would already be at 50MHz. One way to obtain 65MHz is with a PLL that multiplies the freq. first and then divides to obtain the 65MHz. For example you could multiply 100MHz by 13, then divide by 20 and obtain 65MHz.

Comment: On the Artix specifically, you want to use a DCM (digital clock manager) module, which can multiply and divide frequencies by a large range of factors. 65/100 would be no problem at all.

Comment: Another option is to get a _very_ jittery, on-average-65 MHz output.

Comment: How do we do that @pipe ...?

Comment: The resulting signal would be so bad that I don't even want to discuss it. Let's hope @DaveTweed writes an actual answer for you.

Comment: @DaveTweed ...Can you elaborate on it as to how to use DCM?

Comment: Read the documentation: [7 Series FPGAs Clocking Resources User Guide (UG472)](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf). Apparently, they're now called "Clock Management Tiles". There will be a "Wizard" in Vivado to help you configure it.

Comment: @pipe, you can't even do that because 65 MHz is more than half of 100 MHz. At least not without messing around with combinatorial logic on the 100 MHz clock.

Comment: @ThePhoton Good point, didn't even think about that. But the idea is stupid anyway, the resulting output would (likely) be completely unusable...

Comment: How did you determine that you need a 65MHz clock? I know that the standard VGA monitors do 640x480 @ 60fps and require 25.2MHz pixel clock. Check out this answer http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271148/is-55ns-sram-fast-enough-to-drive-low-resolution-vga/271161#271161

Comment: I'm trying to drive a display for 1024X768 @60Hz. See the link:
http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/s2004/NEWKIT/vga.shtml

Comment: I see. You can use clock wizard IP block to create the approximate clock. Also, how do you connect your monitor to FPGA? Do you have a driver?

Comment: I use a standard VGA cable. What is this IP block?

Comment: [Clock wizard](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/clk_wiz/v5_3/pg065-clk-wiz.pdf). Standard VGA cable does not produce standard VGA signal - it's just a wire. You need something that will generate appropriate control signals. I know that this is not related to the question, but you may encounter this problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I used the Clocking Wizard which is a part of Vivado, thanks to @Naz for pointing me in the right direction. Clocking Wizard creates a module for you and depending upon your specifications, you can generate any clock frequency from that module.

The Clocking Wizard can be found in Project Manger->IP Catalog->FPGA Features and Design->Clocking.

For further details regarding the correct usage of Clocking Wizard, I referred to the follwing link:
http://gadgetfactory.net/learn/2017/02/22/fpga-clocking-clocking-wizard-in-xilinx-ise/#Run_the_clocking_wizard_to_generate_your_desired_clocks

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to instantiate a DCM or PLL to do this. See the clocking section in the manual for the FPGA you're using for how to do this properly. You'll need to do something like 100 MHz / 10 * 65 / 10 = 65 MHz or perhaps  100 MHz * 13 / 20 = 65 MHz. You'll have to make sure to get the VCO operating in the proper frequency range.

Comment: You have to make sure you do not pass the maximum limit of the DCM or the PLL, just read the UG472 for help. The best way to do this is using the guide that comes with Vivado to create the right block/settings.